# What should I user to made API centric Web Application. CMS or any MVC Framework?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, frameworks, content-management-system

My requirement is to build API centric Web Application like I need to fetch Faceboook , Twitter , LinkedIn Feeds for particular user. As well as user can comment, share, like as he or she can do it in FB, twitter or LinkedIn.

User can update status also from the web application

Comment: so, what is your actual question?

Comment: My actual question is should i Use any CMS or go for framework to build the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMS a content management system so it is mainly aimed at helping the **administrator** of the site to add new content, update links, better SEO etc. It also enforces the developer to develope in a certain way (use some CMS predefined functions, structure data in a certain way).

MVC framework are meant to help **developers** develop in a more robust way and giving the developer tools for easier development like: structured URLs (MVC), helper functions etc.

So  to summarize:

1. CMS - helps during development but mainly helps manage the site
2. MVN FW - helps to develop the site